# Fix cube position on window ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm working with `Three.JS` and I need a cube to fit the size of the window. The cube will always respect the proportion of the window (`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`) but causes the Z position depending on the display ratio closer or farther away.

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( windowWidth, windowHeight, 200, 6, 6, 6, materials ), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() ); 
cube.position.y = ???; 
cube.position.z = ???;

function onWindowResize() {

   camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
   cube.position.y = ???; 
   cube.position.z = ???;
}
```

Can you think of a solution?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense for me really, what kind of cube ? where ? put some examples of code ... etc.. look at FAQ how to ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Can you provide a live jsfiddle showing what you have so far, and then explain what it is you want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you are having problems with the `cube Z` position.
Well, first of all I would not recommend you to set the position on `windowresize()` and would say do it on animate. Such as:

```
function animate() {
    cube.position.z = camera.position.z  
}
```

Forgive me but I can't understand any further.